# how can i set notifyicon under timer in c#

Tags: c#

not showing the notifyIcon while running?Above Is my Code.Only sound is there

```
   private void timerS_Tick(object sender, EventArgs ex)
    {

             if (File.Exists(path) == true)
            {
                notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "PLEASE CHECK ASHIDA\\MESSAGE\\Temp.txt";
                notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "MESSAGE FROM MUFITHA";
                notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(3000);
                System.Media.SoundPlayer s = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
                s.SoundLocation = @"\\SERVER-HARMONY\Ashida\MESSAGE\click_x.wav";
                s.Play();
                timerS.Stop();
                notifyIcon1.Dispose();
                timerS.Enabled = false;
                return;
            }
```

Comment: You are disposing of the icon in this if block, I don't see where you are creating it. That may be part of your problem.

Comment: private void timerS_Tick(object sender, EventArgs ex)
        {                                                                                                              
          //here i call my code
         }

Answer (score 0):

Before the statement:

```
notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(3000);
```

Try inserting the statement:

```
notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
```